# Como hacer que mi aplicación Angular se comunique utilizando el protocolo HTTP/2

Tags: angular, http, seguridad, backend, frontend

tengo una falla de seguridad en mi aplicacion angular, esta se comunica por HTTP

el fallo esque esta utiliznado la version de HTTP/1, y se requiere utilizar HTTP/2

mi aplicacion angular corre en el puerto 8100, el backend en el puerto 26021

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver el servidor backend responde con HTTP/2, mientras que nuestra app de angular responder con HTTP/1, esto hace que el servidor tambien responda con HTTP/1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para levantar mi app de angular ejecuto el siguiente comando:

```
ionic serve --ssl -- --ssl-key desarrollo.key --ssl-cert desarrollo.cer
```

**Alguien sabe como hacer que mi app en angular utilize el protocolo HTTP/2 ?**

Comment: El servidor que levantas con `ionic serve` no está pensado para usarse en producción. Lo usual es compilar la aplicación (`build`) y hacer el *deploy* en un Servidor como Apache o nginx. Son éstos los que se encargarán del tema SSL y la versión del protocolo HTTP. Saludos